# How to take pg_dump of a very large postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-8.4

I have a production database server running Postgres 8.4 on Cent OS 6.5.The volume of data has increased recently and within few months database now has 18500 tables amounting to approx 350GB database size.

Problem is now I can't even take a pg_dump of this database, Every time I try  I get **OutOfSharedMemory** error for **max_number_of_shared_locks** (current value is **256** instead of **default 64**) ?

How can we take dump of such a huge database ? please help..

Comment: Have you restarted the DB after changing the parameter?  Are all the tables in the same schema?

Comment: Yes!! there is just one schema I started database several times after changing the parameter.. What can be the max value of this parameter for a 32GB machine ?

Comment: By the way, having 18500 tables in your database is outrageous, not because it is a large number, but because it is almost certainly indicative of a schema gone very wrong. And the solution is not merely to split your database into multiple databases.

Comment: @A-B-B I I agree, please see my answer below to understand the problem and the way I solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that some database procedures who did following tasks stopped working due to some newly introduced errors. The procedures performed below tasks:-

1. summarize the data
2. insert summary data in other table
3. truncate table (to reduce the size and prevent creation of new table)

That is why almost 15K+ tables were created due to this side effect.

I did below things to solve this problem:

1. Solved the errors in procedure logic so that it starts doing its works so that no new tables are NOT created.
2. Created Special procedures to periodically summarize the  backlogs of tables (those 15K+ tables which were not summarized).
3. Once summary is created correctly instead of truncating I just dropped the table.

Instead  of doing step 2 and 3 at once I did in batches and within 2-3 days I got database reduced significantly and after that I was able to take pg_dump.

Thanks all for your help..

Answer (score 3):

Hello you need to [change max_locks_per_transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-locks.html) in the postgresql.conf file typically located in /var/lib/pgsql/data or wherever you installed the data directory for PostgreSQL.

Which was already answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29699/backup-a-database-with-a-huge-number-of-tables)

You will have to restart the PostgreSQL Service.

The answer above also talks about having to possibly increase shared memory. Here is a [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/kernel-resources.html) to a PostgreSQL article on that subject.

Comment: Thanks for the link... However I have already changed the value of max_locks_per_transaction  parameter, hope the link will give me some useful pointers.. Thanks !!

Comment: @Amit I just included a link to the other part of the answer which includes increasing the maximum amount of shared memory available.

Comment: I already read that link.. But I have no idea what will be its consequences for other applications and for OS itself. Since this is a live system and without backup I didn't want to screw up things..

Comment: @Amit Can you add the pg_dump command you are using?

Comment: @Amit and what is the current setting of `max_connections`?

Comment: @Amit, you have a strange way of thanking people, removing 15 points from their reputation :(